# Find the smallest subset of overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm, graph, intervals, greedy

Consider a question to find a minimum dominating set of an interval graph. In the context of interval scheduling, it is converted to the question below:

There are multiple intervals which may or may overlap with each other.
Find a minimum subset of the intervals, so that for every interval that is not included in the subset, it will find at least 1 interval in the subset that will overlap with it.

There is an agreed greedy solution available from various sources on the Internet, such as one solution from Cornell:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4820/2011sp/handouts/samplesolutions.pdf

> We work to fill up a set C which makes up the committee (subset of
>   intervals). We use a set M to hold ’covered’ intervals for
>   bookkeeping.
>
> 1. Sort the intervals by finish time with earliest finish time first.
> 2. Take the interval i in S with earliest finish time.
> 3. Construct set O = {s ∈ S|s intersects i}
> 4. Take o ∈ O with the latest finish time and add o to C, add all the intervals that intersect with o to M
> 5. repeat 2-4 until all intervals are covered.

This is similar to a voted up answer provided by interjay in 2012 on SO:
[Find the smallest set of overlapping jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076934/find-the-smallest-set-of-overlapping-jobs)

But I have noticed a counterexample that proves the above solution does not produce the minimum subset:

Consider intervals: [0,2], [1,4], [3,10], [5, 6], [7,8], [9, 10].

A minimum subset should have 2 intervals: [3, 10] plus either [0, 2] or [1, 4].

But the above solution will return a subset of 4 intervals: [1,4], [5,6], [7,8] and [9,10]. The longest interval [3,10] was prematurely rejected at step 4.

Is there a better greedy solution than the ones posted above? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you quoted is incorrect because the set S never changes, so in step 2 the same interval will always be picked and you will enter an infinite loop. If you change step 2 to "Take the interval i in S-M with earliest finish time.", it will be correct.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078090/189205) which you linked is correct however. Both it and the corrected algorithm above will give the set {[1,4], [3,10]} for your example.

The mistake you're making may be that in step 3 above (or step 2 in my linked answer) you're looking only at sets which are in S-M (called A in my answer). But you should look at all intervals that intersect i, even if they are already in M.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, interjay! Because of my embarrassingly small number of reputation points, I was not able to comment on your answer from the link directly, so I opened a new question here. I chose your answer here as the correct answer, but was not able to vote up also because of lack of reputation points. lol. Best!